# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.core.backends.native' has no attribute 'set_remote_python_execution_context'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated

I have the following code:

```
import grpc

ip_address = ['0.0.0.0'] * n_workers  #@param {type:"string"}
ports = [80+i for i in range(n_workers)]  #@param {type:list["integer"]}

channels = [grpc.insecure_channel(f'{ip_address[i]}:{ports[i]}') for i in range(len(ports))]
tff.backends.native.set_remote_python_execution_context(channels)
```

when I run this part of code I got this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.core.backends.native' has no attribute 'set_remote_python_execution_context'
```

I know `set_remote_python_execution_context` is deprecated,
but how can I fix this?

I tried to use `cpp` executions based on `tff` released-notes, but none of them didn't exactly same as `set_remote_python_execution_context`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this API was removed in the [`0.50.0` release](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/releases/tag/v0.50.0) back in 2023-02-23.

To find out what version is installed, use:

```
pip show tensorflow-federated
```

To use a version before `0.50.0`, use:

```
pip install --force-reinstall "tensorflow-federated==0.49.0"
```